# Can consumption of large quantity of eggs (with yolks) be harmful for health?

Tags: nutrition

I have seen people throwing egg yolk while eating egg.

Bodybuilders who take large quantities of egg (50 per day) if they eat yolk is there a health complication compared to eating only egg white.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about nutrition are only on topic if they are directly connected to medical treatments.

Comment: I think we have already answered a lot of questions asking if some food is good or bad for health, the answers were well accepted and had nothing to do with treatment.

Comment: @Jan Not since the site's change of scope unless I missed one, but what was allowed in the past doesn't change what the [scope document](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says.

Comment: According to the scope document, this question is about public health and about medical research. There have been few very interesting recent questions about purines and gout, alcohol, fructose and both the questions and answers were well accepted. The evidence about cholesterol, fructose, saturated fat and some other nutrients is changing in last years, so this is worth of discussion.

Comment: @Jan If this question is about public health then virtually all nutrition questions are about public health. And how can this be answered, anyway? The question is quite specifically if egg yolks make you fat. It doesn't ask about cholesterol, saturated fats, or anything else -- only if yolks make you fat. The answer to that will always be "it depends."

Comment: There is another much more important question there - can consumption of large quantities of eggs (as it is actually a practice in some bodybuilders) be harmful for health? It's this part I'm talking about.

Comment: @Jan In meta discussions regarding nutrition questions, the community has consistently been very negative toward them. For example, see [this](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/is-this-question-really-an-off-topic-one/1038#1038), and [this](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-sort-of-nutrition-or-environmental-questions-are-suitable-now/1014#1014).

Comment: I can imagine a question about egg yolks that would meet site requirements, but I don't see how this one can be edited to make it fit. If you think it can, then go for it, but the bit about weight gain has to go. The question has to have a direct connection to medical care, not just health in general.

Comment: The question asks if there are any health risk of eating large quantity of eggs with emphasis on egg yolks. This is a proper medical question that has got a lot of attention lately because of the changing attitude toward dietary cholesterol. Answers can be directly helpful for a lot of people.

Comment: Whether or not this question is on-topic due to being about public health etc., there is no prior research information provided so therefore this question would be put on hold because of that.  Therefore, I have voted to keep this question on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

1. Egg yolks can make you fat only if they contribute to excessive calorie intake.
2. Consumption of up to 1 whole egg/day does not increase the risk of heart disease, but may increase the risk of diabetes; the risk of both diseases increases with the egg quantity.
3. Egg whites are not typically associated with increased risk of disease.
4. The idea behind throwing egg yolks away is to get the "good" (protein) from the egg white and to avoid the "bad" (fat, cholesterol and calories) from the yolk. But, egg yolk also contains protein, the fat in it is mostly unsaturated and the cholesterol from it does not raise blood cholesterol in most people. It is true that most of egg calories come from the yolk: the [whole 50 g egg](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/01123?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=egg%20raw&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=) has 72 Calories and 55 Calories come from [yolk](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/01125?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=egg%20raw&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=).

It is estimated that in ~2/3 of population, high dietary cholesterol intake does not result in increased blood cholesterol levels, but it can in the other 1/3, who are "cholesterol hyper-responders;" this does not increase the LDL/HDL ratio (which is a risk factor for atherosclerosis) [Nutrients, 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4586539/)).

According to 2 systematic reviews of studies ([AJCN, 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3683816/) ; [Nutrients, 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4586539/)), consumption of up to 1 egg per day is not associated with increased risk of heart disease and stroke but may be associated with an increased risk of diabetes type 2 - this association was manly reported from studies in *Americans,* who tend to be more obese and consume more saturated fats and cholesterol than people in other countries ([British Journal of Nutrition, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27108219)).

In 2 recent systematic reviews ([Advanced Nutrition, 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31041448) ; [European Journal of Nutrition, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24500371)), high egg consumption (>1 egg/meal) was associated with an increased risk of some gastrointestinal cancers.

Comment: So in short need to burn what we eat otherwise there are risk.

Comment: If you burn what you eat you won't get fat. BUT, even if you burn all the calories from eggs, excessive egg consumption (>7 eggs/week) can still be a risk for diabetes, for example.

Comment: risk for diabetes with egg is a new information thanks